# Equivalence of two definitions of smoothly homotopic

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

(Setting: $M$,$N$ :smooth manifolds with boundary,  $f_0$,$f_1$: $M\to N$:smooth maps)

There are (at least) two definitions of smoothly homotopic:

$\bf{(1)}$ If there is a smooth map $H:M\times \mathbb{R}\to N$ such that $H(-,i)=f_i\ \ (i=0,1)$, then $f_0$ and $f_1$ are smoothly homotopic.

$\bf{(2)}$ If there is a smooth map $H:U\to N$ where $U$ is some neighborhood of $M\times I$ in $M\times \mathbb{R}$ such that $H(-,i)=f_i\ \ (i=0,1)$, then $f_0$ and $f_1$ are smoothly homotopic.

Tu's book ("An Introduction to Manifolds") adopts (1), and Lee's book ("Introduction to Smooth manifolds") adopts (2). These two definitions are equivalent? If so, could you tell me its proof or any references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will prove $\mathbf{(2)}\implies \mathbf{(1)}$. Consider a smooth bump function $\mathcal B\colon \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ such that

$a)$ $\mathcal B(x)=0$ for $x\leq 0$;

$b)$  $0<\mathcal B(x)<1$ for $0<x<1$;

$c)$ $\mathcal B(x)=1$ for $x\geq 1$.

---

Let $M, N$ be smooth manifolds, and $H\colon U\to N$ be a smooth function, where $U$ is an open neighborhood of $M\times [0,1]$ in $M\times \Bbb R$.

Define, $\overline H\colon M\times \Bbb R\to N$ as $$\overline H(x,t):=H\big(x,\mathcal B(t)\big)\text{ for all }(x,t)\in M\times \Bbb R.$$ Note that for each $x\in M$ we have $\varepsilon_x>0$ such that $\{x\}\times (0-\varepsilon_x,1+\varepsilon_x)\subseteq U$. So, $\overline H$ is a well-defined smooth function, such that $\overline H(-,0)=H(-,0)$ and $\overline H(-,1)=H(-,1)$.

---

To construct such $\mathcal B$ consider $\psi:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ given by $$\psi(x)=\begin{cases}\exp\left(\frac{1}{x(x-1)}\right)& \text{ if }0<x<1,\\ 0 & \text{ otherwise}.\end{cases}$$ Now, consider $$\mathcal B(x):=\frac{\displaystyle\int_0^x\psi(t)\ \mathrm{d}t}{\displaystyle\int_0^1\psi(t)\ \mathrm{d}t}\text{ for all }x\in \Bbb R.$$

Comment: Thank you for answering. Your proof can be applied for  manifolds with boundary, right？

Comment: Yes, it does also hold for manifold with boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly (1) implies (2). The fact that (2) implies (1) appears to be somewhat subtle.

In case that the manifolds have no boundary, this follows from the [collar neighborhood theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/collar+neighbourhood+theorem) (let me call it CNT). In any case, take a collar neighborhood of $U\smallsetminus (M\times [0,1])$. This has two components, each diffeomorphic to $M\times [0,1)$; choose your favorite smooth map $[0,1)\to\Bbb R_{\geq 0}$ and pull it back to the components. Everything in sight is smooth so the appropriate compositions will transform $H$ from a map on $V \cup (M\times [0,1])$ (not $U$!) to a smooth map $M\times [0,1]\to N$.

This result is intuitive but the details of the CNT do require some machinery, so I wonder if there is a simpler argument. To this end, when the manifolds do have boundary, the same argument should work except that you need a suitable CNT variant. Apparently nobody bothers to write such things down, although it seems to me that [Lemma 2.1.6 of this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2000-352-12/S0002-9947-00-02676-3/S0002-9947-00-02676-3.pdf) is equivalent.

(*NB: The first answer was completely incorrect, hence the odd first comments.*)

Comment: (NB: it's possible that this only works as written for compact manifolds; it's been a while since I needed to worry about in what generality bump functions exist. But in this case one simply has to go chart-by-chart and make some annoying partition of unity argument.)

Comment: Thank you for answering. I can't understand what b(x)H(x) represents because I don't assume that N has some vector space structure. Could you explain it?

Comment: @imsh: this should be much more relevant to the question, my apologies.

Comment: Thanks. I will confirm details including with-boundary version by myself.